# Cannot extract data from command line as expected

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream

I have a courses0.dat file with a single 4 on line 1 that I want to extract with my ifstream program:

```
void processEnrollments (std::istream& courseFile);

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

// Take input and output file names from the command line
ifstream coursesIn (argv[1]);

return 0;
}

void processEnrollments (istream& courseFile)
{
int numCourses;
courseFile >> numCourses;

cout << numCourses;

// Create the arrays we need
//!! Insert your code here
}
```

when I run

```
program courses0.dat
```

my test is cout'ing a 32767 instead of a 4. My .dat file is in the same directory as my executable.

any clue as to what is going on?

thanks

Comment: Given that we don't even know what's in courses0.dat, how should we be able to tell what's wrong...

Comment: I do not see how you get any output because `processEnrollments` is not even called.

Comment: Yeah, well, you're relying too much on `operator >>` to do "the right thing". Just consider extra gibberish in the file, blank lines, etc... Go for `std::getline` and start from there.

Comment: My first sentence was: "I have a courses0.dat file with a single 4 on line 1 that I want to extract with my ifstream program:"

Comment: @nobody I'm sorry, I mean to include:   processEnrollments (coursesIn); In my main; it's in my program, I just forgot to include it in the post.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I am not allowed to edit the program except after where it says "insert your code here"

Comment: @Joey In this case, you might consider it useful to go ask your teacher for help. On a more serious note, just open courses0.dat in a smart text editor, let's say Notepad++, make all characters visible and see exactly what it has inside. You may even encounter some strange issues with UTF8, if it is in that format...

Comment: Your code has no error checking or reporting, which makes it very hard to tell what's wrong. Did `courseFile >> numCourses` succeed? Was `argc` 2? Did opening `coursesIn` succeed? Who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for errors! Try to use the full path to the file when you pass it as an argument.

My guess is `courseFile >> numCourses;` fails because `ifstream coursesIn (argv[1])` doesn't find or can't access the file.

Try this

```
if( courseFile >> numCourses )
    cout << numCourses;
```

Does it output anything then?

Comment: Thanks for being helpful :) Your reply was the first who actually didn't sound they were talking down to me. I appreciate it.

My problem was xcode. I compiled using g++ from the terminal, all in the same directory, and it seems to all be going fine.